# how to take screenshot of my whole city from google maps in maximum possible zoom?

Tags: google-maps

how to take screenshot of my whole city from google maps in maximum possible zoom position?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could follow this video tutorial: **[Google Map hack: How to save large maps](http://www.metacafe.com/watch/1073912/google_maps_hack_how_to_save_large_maps/)**

Alternatively you could also try the **[Google Map Saver](http://www.codres.de/google-map-saver)** application.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open and maximize your browser and get your map the way you want it. You can hide the left side of the window. When you have the zoom and center where you want it, press <kbd>F11</kbd> to hide the browser toolbars and make the browser window as large as possible. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Print Screen</kbd> to capture your screen to the clipbaord. You can paste the captured image into your favorite program graphics capable program. <kbd>F11</kbd> again returns your browser to normal.

Comment: no my whole city map is bigger than my monitor screen

Comment: or get a bigger monitor :p

Comment: You can either zoom out until your whole city fits into your monitor, or you can zoom in and capture sections of your city. Save each section as a graphics file and move the map around and capture sections until you have your entire city. You can then use some stiching software to create a single large image that still won't fit completely on your monitor at once or print each image and paste / tape them into a larger map.